Passing data from list to slider
I want to pass this productlist to the carousel slider so when someone navigate to details screen they can see different pictures. The first one (product 1) is passing, but the other products are not passing to the slider. What Could the reason for this problem?
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:ecommerce_app/Model/datamodel1.dart';
import 'package:ecommerce_app/Model/slidermodel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Detailscreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Detailscreen({super.key, required this.model});

  final Datamodel1 model;

  final List<Slidermodel> productlist = [
    Slidermodel(imageurl: [
      "assets/images/watch 11.png",
      "assets/images/10.png",
      "assets/images/12.png",
      "assets/images/13.png",
    ], name: "product1"),
    Slidermodel(imageurl: [
      "assets/images/watch 12.png",
      "assets/images/21.png",
      "assets/images/22.png",
      "assets/images/23.png"
    ], name: "Product2"),
    Slidermodel(imageurl: [
      "assets/images/watch 33.png",
      "assets/images/31.png",
      "assets/images/32.png",
      "assets/images/33.png"
    ], name: "product3"),
    Slidermodel(imageurl: [
      "assets/images/watch 44.png",
      "assets/images/41.png",
      "assets/images/42.png",
      "assets/images/43.png"
    ], name: "product4"),
    Slidermodel(imageurl: [
      "assets/images/watch 55.png",
      "assets/images/51.png",
      "assets/images/52.png",
      "assets/images/53.png"
    ], name: "product5"),
    Slidermodel(imageurl: [
      "assets/images/watch 66.png",
      "assets/images/61.png",
      "assets/images/62.png",
    ], name: "product6"),
    Slidermodel(imageurl: [
      "assets/images/watch 77.png",
      "assets/images/81.png",
      "assets/images/82.png",
      "assets/images/83.jpg",
    ], name: "product7"),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Expanded(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(model.title),
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.favorite,
              ))
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 400,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
            ),
            child: CarouselSlider.builder(
              itemCount: productlist.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, productIndex, _) {
                final product = productlist[productIndex];
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                        itemCount: product.imageurl.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, imageIndex, _) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                            child: Hero(
                              tag: product.imageurl[imageIndex],
                              child: Image.asset(
                                product.imageurl[imageIndex],
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        options: CarouselOptions(
                          height: 300,
                          viewportFraction: 1,
                          enlargeCenterPage: true,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                   
                  ],
                );
              },
              options: CarouselOptions(
                height: 400,
                viewportFraction: 1.0,
                enlargeCenterPage: true,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


(not the downvoter) Can you clarify what you mean by "the other products are not passing to the slider" in a way that we can also see? Is there an error message?

As you can see there are datamodel named like product 1, product 2. The problem I am facing is only the product 1 is showing in th carousel slider but I want all the remaining products datamodels to pass in carousel slider. How to to that? And there is no error in the debugging console

Hmmm.... I don't immediately see what could be causing that. Can you set up a repro on https://zapp.run/ for this? I would've done that myself, but datamodel1.dart and slidermodel.dart are missing. So I also recommend reading How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example, as following the guidance there drastically increases the chances that we can help.
